# Verification of solution of a contest problem with a limit of nested radicals

Tags: limits, proof-verification, problem-solving, nested-radicals

They gave me 0 points for this problem. I think it's unfair. What do you think of this proof, is it correct?

> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \underset{2n\text{ roots }}{\underbrace{\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15}\dots\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15}}}}}}}$
>   $x_n=\underset{2n\text{ roots }}{\underbrace{\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15}\dots\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15}}}}}}}$
>   $x_1=\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15}}$
>   $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15x_n}}=\sqrt[6]{20^3\cdot15x_n}=\sqrt[6]{120000x_n}$
>   Let's prove that $x_n<\sqrt[5]{120000}$
>
> 1. Basis
>      $n=1$; $x_1=\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15}}=\sqrt[6]{120000}<\sqrt[5]{120000}$
> 2. Inductive step
>      given that $x_n<\sqrt[5]{120000}$ let's prove that $x_{n+1}<\sqrt[5]{120000}$
>      $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[6]{120000x_n}$
>      $x_{n+1}^5=\sqrt[6]{120000^5x_n^5} < \sqrt[6]{120000^5\cdot120000}=\sqrt[6]{120000^6}=120000$
>      then
>      $x_{n+1}<\sqrt[5]{120000}$
>      Q.E.D.
>
> Then
>   $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{\sqrt[6]{120000x_n}}{x_n} = \frac{\sqrt[6]{120000}}{x_n^{5/6}} = \sqrt[6]{\frac{120000}{x^5}} > \sqrt[6]{\frac{120000}{120000}} =1$
>   $x_{n+1}>x_n$
>   $\{x_n\}$ is bound from above and increasing, then it has a limit
>   Let's denote it as $x$, then
>   $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[6]{120000}x_n$
>   $x=\sqrt[6]{120000x}$
>   $x^6=120000x$
>   $x_n>1$ thus $x\ge1$ than $x\ne0$
>   $x=\sqrt[5]{120000}$
>   $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \underset{2n\text{ roots }}{\underbrace{\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15}\dots\sqrt{20\sqrt[3]{15}}}}}}}= \sqrt[5]{120000}$

[image]

Comment: If f(x) < M, then f(x) < M + n. How can you say that $\sqrt[5]{120000}$ is the upper bound? It could be lower than that.

Comment: 6th line from the bottom, in the recurrent expression I let n -> infinity and get the equation for x

Comment: Your proof seems perfectly valid to me, so 0 points is probably unfair. However, I do think it could use some elaboration at places, especially since it is heavily reliant on calculations.

BTW, you could have made this much simpler by taking the log on both sides, which would yield some simple geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof in general looks absolutely correct (and fairly standard) to me, and if partial credit is possible I would not consider this to be worth $0$ points.

I do see two points where there might be some slight complaint: first you might want to specifically reference the monotone convergence theorem, and second you should justify your claim that $x_n>1$ in the third to last line (this statement can be easily proven via induction), but these are very minor qualms.